# Project dependencies option in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there any option of project dependencies in VS Code like we have in Pycharm. I tried "vscode-solution-explorer" extension but no use for python projects. I have created a workspace with three projects inside it, want to add project dependencies between them, how can i achieve that? In Pycharm we have a "project dependencies" option. want to configure the same in VS Code

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyCharm, but looking at [ther docs on Project Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-dependencies.html), if this is just about configuring `PYTHONPATH`, you can at least get somewhere [with this answer](/a/75543310).

Comment: You can [package your Python code](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to achieve the same purpose.